# iOS Reload tableview properly when there is change in font in setting

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have written this to listen for font changes in setting.

```
func setUpNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(reloadTable),
                                           name: .UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange,
                                           object: nil)

}

func reloadTable() {
    self.tblListing.reloadData()
}
```

I also set font like this.

```
self.subheadLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline]; 
//This is for example only.
```

After user change font and come back to app, it actually change font. Problem is that when my tableview show 2 cell (those are visible), it only change to 1 cell although whole tableview is successfully reloaded. They are created using self-sizing cell and my constraints are okay too. May I know how to solve this?

Comment: Your problem can be anything can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method? or the way you are using to reload your tableView?

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider `estimadedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` properties of your `tableView`. Example:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 89 //Height that is applicable for you
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

**Edit:** If that doesn't help, take [a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33059363/3687801)